# Iterate and Modify each element and return output List

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I need to iterate through each tags in the below XML and after checking some condition, I need to generate an output XML

Input XML :

```
<NameList>
   <Name>
       <Name>test1</Name>
       <nameType>
          <set>nameType</set>
          <entry>set3</entry>
       </nameType>
   </Name>
   <Name>
       <Name>test2</Name>
       <nameType>
         <set>nameType</set>
         <entry>set4</entry>
       </nameType>
   </Name>
<NameList>
```

Conditions needs to be applied in the Input XML:

- if entry == set3, then add a tag
- if entry == set4, then set the whole tag as empty

Output XML will look like :

```
<NameList>
           <Name>
               <Name>test1</Name>
               <nameType>
                  <set>nameType</set>
                  <entry>set3</entry>
                  <date>2022-03-03</date>
               </nameType>
           </Name>
        <NameList>
```

Implementation code :

```
nameList.stream()
      .forEach(name -> {
         if(name.getNameType().getEntry().equals("set3")) {
            name.setDate(date);
         } 
         if (name.getNameType().getEntry().equals("set4")) {
           name.setName(null);
           name.setDate(null);
           ........
        }   
      }
```

Using the above code, it is setting null to name object and I'm getting output as

```
<NameList/>
```

Comment: You don't need a stream to call `forEach()`.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do and what's going wrong from this small snippet. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (safely) use `.forEach` to remove elements from a collection and you certainly cannot use it to remove elements from a stream. (not entirely true: streams are more or less read-only).

Instead, you want to `filter` your stream:

```
var filteredNameList = nameList.stream()
      .filter(name -> !name.getNameType().getEntry().equals("set4"))
      .collect(Collectors.toList();

filteredNameList
      .forEach(name -> {
         if(name.getNameType().getEntry().equals("set3")) {
            name.setDate(date);
         }
      );
```

The second statement could again be replaced with a filtered stream to mutate the underlying collection, making it conciser:

```
filteredNameList.stream()
      .filter(name -> name.getNameType().getEntry().equals("set3"))
      .forEach(name -> name.setDate(date));
```